# How do I calculate the duration my solar battery will last when fully charged?

Tags: batteries

How can I calculate the duration my solar battery will last after charging to full?
I want to know how to calculate the battery back up time.

Answer (score 1):

Batteries are typically rated with a **capacity** value, which is current times time. For example, 12Ah (ampere hours) or 300mAh (milliampere hours). If the amount of current you are drawing from the battery is similar to the current that the manufacturer used when specifying the capacity then you can just divide the capacity by the current, and the result will be time in hours.

This does not work if the current you are drawing is much less than or much greater than the current that the manufacturer used when specifying the capacity.